# Problema CORS en Angular 2 y PHP

Tags: php, angular, cors

Tengo un servidor REST para consultas a una base de datos corriendo en *PHP*, el cual vía **GET** se pueden consultar varios datos en formato **JSON**.

Anteriormente existía un cliente en otro servidor escrito en *Javascript* + *JQuery*, por lo que necesitaba usar **CORS** para conectarme a dicho servidor. En ese momento solo hacía falta agregar las siguientes líneas a la página PHP:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Ahora estoy migrando el cliente a **Angular2**, pero resulta que al intentar conectarme al mismo servidor rechaza las peticiones CORS.

En principio creo que es del lado del servidor más que del cliente, pero *¿por qué si antes funcionaba ahora dejó de funcionar para Angular2?*.

Las peticiones angular son de este tipo:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let url = this.apiHost + '/servicios/';
return this.http.get(url, options).map(response => response.json());
```

Comment: que mensaje se supone que te aparece, para saber cual es el problema

Comment: El clásico mensaje de petición cors rechazada `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver/datos.php Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` (*Nota la url del server esta modificada a propósito.*)

Comment: bueno quizás sea yo, pero esta mal puesto lo del asterisco, segun esta pagina, [todo acerca de los cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html), dice que es asi ` header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`, segun veo, la diferencia es usar comillas dobles

Comment: Perdon @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales si están con comillas dobles fue un error mio cambiarlas al transcribirlo, funciona sin problemas para peticiones Javascript + JQuery normales, con Angular 2 es cuando se lía.

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo angular a ver que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es porque [la especificación de CORS indica que en las solicitudes simples deben cumplirse las siguientes condiciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Solicitudes_simples):

- Los únicos métodos aceptados son:

  - `GET`
  - `HEAD`
  - `POST`
- Aparte de los encabezados establecidos automáticamente por el agente usuario (ej. `Connection`, `User-Agent`,etc.), los únicos encabezados que están permitidos para establecer manualmente son:

  - `Accept`
  - `Accept-Language`
  - `Content-Language`
  - `Content-Type`
- Los únicos valores permitidos del encabezado `Content-Type` son:

  - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `multipart/form-data`
  - `text/plain`

Las aplicaciones desarrolladas con jQuery cumplen estas condiciones, pero las desarrolladas con Angular no ya que [`$http` cambia la cabecera `Content-type` a `application/json`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers):

> The `$http` service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all requests. These defaults can be fully configured by accessing the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` configuration object, which currently contains this default configuration:
>
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` (headers that are common for all requests):
>
>   - `Accept`: `application/json`, `text/plain`, `*/*`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post`: (header defaults for `POST` requests)
>
>   - `Content-Type`: `application/json`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put` (header defaults for `PUT` requests)
>
>   - `Content-Type`: `application/json`

En castellano:

> El servicio `$http` agregará automáticamente algunas cabeceras HTTP a todas las peticiones. Pueden ser completamente configuradas a través del objeto de configuración `$httpProvider.defaults.headers`, que actualmente contiene esta configuración por defecto:
>
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` (cabeceras comunes para todas las peticiones):
>
>   - `Accept`: `application/json`, `text/plain`, `*/*`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post`: (cabecera por defecto para las peticiones `POST`)
>
>   - `Content-Type`: `application/json`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put` (cabecera por defecto para las peticiones `PUT`)
>
>   - `Content-Type`: `application/json`

Así que, como mínimo, debes agregar esto a tu código PHP para que permita dicho cambio realizado por Angular:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

Autorizando explícitamente la cabecera `Content-Type` se podrá usar cualquier valor más allá de los permitidos inicialmente (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` y `text/plain`).

Answer (score 1):

Actualizo el problema se corrigió agregando las siguientes cabeceras

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
```

Completo quedo así:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Aun asi sigo sin entender bien cual fue realmente el problema, para que funcione para uno *javascript + jquery* y no funcione  para *Angular 2*.